# How got the duplicate key's value from rapidjson?

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm new to `rapidjson`, and I have below `json` text:

```
{"Response":"GetAllocations","ResponseCode":200,"ports":[0,1,2],"ports":[3,4,5], "ports":[6,7,8]}
```

How could I extract the values: `0, 1, 2; 3, 4, 5; 6, 7, 8` by key `"ports"`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I have got it works as below code:

```
rapidjson::Document doc;
if (doc.Parse(sssss.c_str()).HasParseError() || !doc.IsObject() || !doc.HasMember("Response") || !doc["Response"].IsString())
{
    return 0;
}

for (SizeType i = 0; i < doc["ports"].Size(); ++i)
{
    cout << "id = " << doc["ports"][0].GetUint() << endl;
    cout << "port1 = " << doc["ports"][1].GetUint() << endl;
    cout << "port2 = " << doc["ports"][2].GetUint() << endl;
}
```